# Formal Proof on why Greedy isn't working on one Particular Problem

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms, correctness-proof

### Problem

[You](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-score-from-performing-multiplication-operations) are given two integer arrays `nums` and `multipliers` of size `n` and `m` respectively, where `n≥m`. The arrays are **1-indexed.**

You begin with a score of `0`. You want to perform **exactly** `m` operations. On the `iᵗʰ` operation **(1-indexed)**, you will:

- Choose one integer `x` from **either the start or the end** of the array `nums`.
- Add `multipliers[i] * x` to your score.
- Remove `x` from the array `nums`.

Return the **maximum** score after performing `m` operations.

---

### Example 1

> **Input**: `nums = [1,2,3]`, `multipliers = [3,2,1]`
> **Output**: `14`
>
> **Explanation**: An optimal solution is as follows:
>
> - Choose from the end, [1,2,**3**], adding `3*3 = 9` to the score.
> - Choose from the end, [1,**2**], adding `2*2 = 4` to the score.
> - Choose from the end, [**1**], adding `1*1 = 1` to the score.
>
> The total score is `9+4+1 = 14`

### Example 2

> **Input**: `nums = [-5,-3,-3,-2,7,1]`, `multipliers = [-10,-5,3,4,6]`
> **Output**: `102`
>
> **Explanation**: An optimal solution is as follows:
>
> - Choose from the start, [**-5**,-3,-3,-2,7,1], adding `-5 * -10 = 50` to the score.
> - Choose from the start, [**-3**,-3,-2,7,1], adding `-3 * -5 = 15` to the score.
> - Choose from the start, [**-3**,-2,7,1], adding `-3 * 3 = -9` to the score.
> - Choose from the end  , [-2,7,**1**], adding `1 * 4 = 4` to the score.
> - Choose from the end  , [-2,**7**], adding `7 * 6 = 42` to the score.
>
> The total score is `50 + 15 - 9 + 4 + 42 = 102`.

---

### My Approach

I tried to solve it using **Dynamic Programming** and formed following [Bellman Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation).

> $X[i][j]$ stores the **maximum possible score** after we have done $i$ total operations and used $j$ numbers from the *left/start* side. The index of the *rightmost* element can be calculated from $n-1-(i-j)$. For purpose of formulation `multipliers` has been renamed to $M$ while `nums` to $N$
> $$
> X[i][j] =
> \begin{cases}
> \text{max}\bigg((M[i]\cdot N[j]) + X[i+1][j+1],\\\quad\quad\quad(M[i]\cdot N[n-1-(i-j)]) + X[i+1][j]\bigg),  & \text{if $i \neq m$ } \\[2ex]
> 0, & \text{if $i=m$}
> \end{cases}
> $$

We essentially choose the **maximum** on choosing from *left* or *right*. If we choose left, next operation will occur at $[i+1][j+1]$, else next operation will occur at $[i+1][j]$.

On writing code for the same, the approach worked fine.

---

### Question

Why Greedy Approach is failing here? On Going Greedy in **Example 2**,

> - [-5,-3,-3,-2,7,1], from `50 vs -10`, choose `50`, hence `left`
> - [-3,-3,-2,7,1], from `15 vs -5`, choose `15`, hence `left`
> - [-3,-2,7,1], from `-9 vs 3`, choose `3`, hence `right`
> - [-3,-2,7], from `-12 vs 28`, choose `28`, hence `right`
> - [-3,-2], from `-18 vs -12`, choose `-12`, hence `right`
>
> The total score is `50 + 15 + 3 + 28 - 12 = 84`, which **isn't** optimal.

Is there a **formal proof** using [eXchange Argument](https://people.cs.pitt.edu/%7Ekirk/cs1510/notes/greedynotes.pdf) [*Although the [link](https://people.cs.pitt.edu/%7Ekirk/cs1510/notes/greedynotes.pdf) suggests that To show that an algorithm A does not solve a problem it is sufficient to exhibit
one input on which A does not produce an acceptable output*] **or** [Greedy Stays Ahead](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1138/handouts/120%20Guide%20to%20Greedy%20Algorithms.pdf) Approach$\color{red}{?}$

Any hint would be of great help. Thanks!

---

Comment: To show that the greedy approach fails, all you have to do is come up with a counterexample. No further proof is needed. Exchange arguments are used to prove that greedy approaches work, and are irrelevant here.

Comment: You have given a formal proof by showing a counterexample. A single counterexample is a full, complete, totally formal proof.

Comment: What you wanted to ask might have been "how can I understand why greedy approach fails for this problem?" or "Why is 'exchange argument/greedy stays ahead' not applicable to this greedy algorithm?"

Comment: (About your style of formatting: all people around here that I know well do not prefer/use a lot of decorations such as boldfaces, italics, quotation marks for non-quotations, many headers. It reads to me like someone who wants to startle me or someone who do not think I am capable of reading or who is not sure of their statements. Of course, you are free to choose your style.)

Comment: "Why Greedy Approach is failing here?" - because a greedy algorithm does not account for much enough data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that the greedy algorithm is not optimal, it suffices to give one counterexample, i.e. one problem instance $nums$ and $mult$ such that it is possible to obtain a value that is larger than the output computed by the greedy algorithm.  You have already shown this. In fact, you showed more than that - you computed the optimal value for this problem instance, which is not necessary - it would have sufficed to show that the greedy algorithm’s output is $84$ and that there exists a sequence of decisions that gives a value larger than $84$, such as $90$, say. It’s not necessary to compute the optimal value $102$ to prove suboptimality of the greedy algorithm.

If you want to understand why the greedy algorithm is not optimal, it helps to find the smallest possible counterexamples.  Suppose $nums=[5,4]$ and $mult=[1,2]$.  Then, the greedy algorithm would choose to multiply the $1$ by a $5$ rather than $4$, giving an output of $1 \cdot 5+2 \cdot 4=13$.  But the second multiplier $2$ is larger than the first multiplier and so should have been multiplied with the larger number $5$ to get the maximum output (which is $1 \cdot 4+2 \cdot5=14$).  We can see why being greedy is suboptimal in general.

Comment: Thanks. This answer and comments were used to publish [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-score-from-performing-multiplication-operations/discuss/2156486/Greedy-Failed-From-Level-Zero-or-Beginner-Friendly-or-Fully-Explained-or-Python-or-C) solution.

Comment: A more extreme example: Say your array starts with 1, 100 and ends with 0, 2.  The next two multipliers are 1 and 100. You’d like to add 100*100, for that you need to add 1*1 in the first step, but your greedy algorithm will add 2*1 and can’t access the 100 in the second step.